# parsing two files and make a corresponding string for each id

Tags: python, linux, bash

I have two files like this:

**p.txt**

```
{1=[128, 12, 132], 2=[137, 1, 141, 5, 129, 9], 3=[2, 138, 6, 142]}
```

**s.txt**

```
{1=[200, 11, 987], 2=[765, 198, 31, 912, 234, 11], 3=[19, 12, 38, 60, 212]}
```

In both the above files, I have primary and secondary mapping for each client id. For example `clientId 1` has `primary` mapping as `128, 12, 132` and `secondary` mapping as `200, 11, 987`. Similarly for other clientId as well. Format of above two files should be same and both the file will have same number of client id.

Now basis on above two files, I need to make a string like this for each clientId so that for each clientId, value of p and s is there.

```
{"text":"For id 1.","p":[128, 12, 132],"s":[200, 11, 987]}
{"text":"For id 2.","p":[137, 1, 141, 5, 129, 9],"s":[765, 198, 31, 912, 234, 11]}
{"text":"For id 3.","p":[2, 138, 6, 142],"s":[19, 12, 38, 60, 212]}
```

What is the best way to do this? Parsing `p.txt` and `s.txt` in bash will be kinda difficult as they are not valid json.

Comment: Don't forget to add your attempt in question

Comment: Apparently the best way for you is to get someone else to do the work. Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ast.literal_eval` for converting string to python object. Of course, your input need some modification before that - using `re` module for example:

```
from ast import literal_eval
import re

p_str = "{1=[128, 12, 132], 2=[137, 1, 141, 5, 129, 9], 3=[2, 138, 6, 142]}"
s_str = "{1=[200, 11, 987], 2=[765, 198, 31, 912, 234, 11], 3=[19, 12, 38, 60, 212]}"

p_str = re.sub(r'(\d+)\=', r'"x\1":', p_str)
s_str = re.sub(r'(\d+)\=', r'"x\1":', s_str)
p_d = literal_eval(p_str)
s_d = literal_eval(s_str)

for k, v in p_d.items():
    print('{{"text": "For id {}.", "p":{},"s":{}}}'.format(k.lstrip('x'), v, s_d[k]))
```

This will print:

```
{"text": "For id 1.", "p":[128, 12, 132],"s":[200, 11, 987]}
{"text": "For id 2.", "p":[137, 1, 141, 5, 129, 9],"s":[765, 198, 31, 912, 234, 11]}
{"text": "For id 3.", "p":[2, 138, 6, 142],"s":[19, 12, 38, 60, 212]}
```

For loading from files you can use this:

```
from ast import literal_eval
import re

with open('p.txt', 'r') as p_in, open('s.txt', 'r') as s_in:
    p_str = p_in.read()
    s_str = s_in.read()

p_str = re.sub(r'(\d+)\=', r'"x\1":', p_str)
s_str = re.sub(r'(\d+)\=', r'"x\1":', s_str)
p_d = literal_eval(p_str)
s_d = literal_eval(s_str)

for k, v in p_d.items():
    print('{{"text": "For id {}.", "p":{},"s":{}}}'.format(k.lstrip('x'), v, s_d[k]))
```

Comment: Is there any way by which I don't have to modify my input files? In real I have around 50 client id's in both of my file. I mean to say, I already have two files created `p.txt` and `s.txt` so wanted to just use them as it is.

Comment: @user5447339 you are not modifying files, to load `p_str` you can use `p_str = open('p.txt', 'r').read()`. Similar with `s_str`. See my edited answer.